# Applying for US Visa in Canada as a visitor in Canada on WX1 Visa

Tags: visas, usa, canada

I am an Indian National who would be travelling to Canada for internship work on multiple entry WX1 Visa for a span of 95 days. I intend to travel to US from there for personal travel reasons. Can I book a visa appointment in one of the Canadian consulate offices for visitor us visa as a third country national who is there in Canada as a visitor?

Also as I am tied up with my organisation for the entire duration of work I can't leave the country before I complete my work duration period? Thus I intend to travel after the staying for 3 months there, from Canada. Can someone tell me is it possible? How much time it takes to get US Visa if I am applying from Canada in my case

Comment: This site https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html gives an indication of appointment wait times, depending on which city in Canada you intend to apply.